# Minimum sample size n such that difference is no more than

Tags: r, function, difference, sample-size

What is the minimum sample size *n* (or the *length n = length(x)* of the data vector *x*) such that the difference *D = 1 - statx4(x)/statx5(x)* of the functions statx4 and statx5 is no more than *1/100* i.e. *D ≤ 1/100*?

And here are the functions:

```
statx4 <- function(x)  {
  numerator <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)
  denominator <- length(x)
  result <- numerator/denominator
  return(result)
}
```

```
statx5 <- function(x)  {
  numerator <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)
  denominator <- length(x)-1
  result <- numerator/denominator
  return(result)
}
```

I've been doing this exercise set for a while, but haven't managed to get anything valid on this question. Could you point me to right direction?

Comment: The function `D` evaluates the difference between the unbiased variance and the ordinal bias.  I think such minimum depends not only the length of vector `x` but also each component of `x`.  If `x` is a constant vector, then, the minimum length is 1, since two functions equals to 0. If we restrict the distribution of `x`, then the answer will be changed.

Comment: Minimum length is 2, as for n = 1 `statx5` will have 0 in the denominator and not be defined, but beyond that, I agree.

Comment: Thanks @shs. I was wrong, for a constant vector `x` the answer is 2.

Comment: I don't want to be pedantic, because it's an interesting question and I'm no statistician, but if you're sampling a random variable then strictly speaking there is no "minimum", because the two statistics and the ratio are themselves random variables. If you mean _expected_ value of D, I think it would depend on the distribution of the thing you're sampling. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: You are right that it's more of a statistics question and is probably better suited for Cross Validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the normal distribution, it is the following:

```
  statx4 <- function(x)  {
  numerator <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)
  denominator <- length(x)
  result <- numerator/denominator
  return(result)
}
statx5 <- function(x)  {
  numerator <- sum((x-mean(x))^2)
  denominator <- length(x)-1
  result <- numerator/denominator
  return(result)
}

D <- function(x){

  1-statx4(x)/statx5(x)
}


DD <- function(N=1111,seed =1){
  set.seed(seed)
  Logi <- vector()
  for (n in 1:N) {
    x<- rnorm(n)
    y <- D(x)
    Logi[n] <- (y  > 1/100) 
  }
  return(Logi)
}

 min  <- vector()
 for (seed in 1:100) {
   message(seed)
   DD(1000,seed)
   min[seed] <-  length(which(DD(1000) == TRUE))
 }

  Answer <- mean(min)+1
Answer
```

Note that the function `D` evaluates the difference of the unbiased variance and the ordinal variance.

I think this problem should be more clear in mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

I got solutions today and all you had to do was guess random values:

```
a <- rnorm(99); 1-statx4(a)/statx5(a)
a <- rnorm(100); 1-statx4(a)/statx5(a)
a <- rnorm(101); 1-statx4(a)/statx5(a)`
```

And correct answer is 100.

Thank you all for help.